# Auto fade between scenes in unity not working on OSX

Tags: c#, opengl, unity-game-engine, osx-yosemite

I just imported my project into unity of my mac. I have unity pro license and I'm using unity 4.6.3 in both computers (pc with windows 8) and OS X yosemite. When i test my project in the pc(windows) the auto fade works ok but when i do it on my mac it waits the time between scenes, but it only put the screen in black with no fading. This is the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AutoFade : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static AutoFade m_Instance = null;
    private Material m_Material = null;
    private string m_LevelName = "";
    private int m_LevelIndex = 0;
    private bool m_Fading = false;

    private static AutoFade Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_Instance == null)
            {
                m_Instance = (new GameObject("AutoFade")).AddComponent<AutoFade>();
            }
            return m_Instance;
        }
    }
    public static bool Fading
    {
        get { return Instance.m_Fading; }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
        m_Instance = this;
        m_Material = new Material("Shader \"Plane/No zTest\" { SubShader { Pass { Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha ZWrite Off Cull Off Fog { Mode Off } BindChannels { Bind \"Color\",color } } } }");
    }

    private void DrawQuad(Color aColor,float aAlpha)
    {
        aColor.a = aAlpha;
        m_Material.SetPass(0);
        GL.Color(aColor);
        GL.PushMatrix();
        GL.LoadOrtho();
        GL.Begin(GL.QUADS);
        GL.Vertex3(0, 0, -1);
        GL.Vertex3(0, 1, -1);
        GL.Vertex3(1, 1, -1);
        GL.Vertex3(1, 0, -1);
        GL.End();
        GL.PopMatrix();
    }

    private IEnumerator Fade(float aFadeOutTime, float aFadeInTime, Color aColor)
    {
        float t = 0.0f;
        while (t<1.0f)
        {
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
            t = Mathf.Clamp01(t + Time.deltaTime / aFadeOutTime);
            DrawQuad(aColor,t);
        }
        if (m_LevelName != "")
            Application.LoadLevel(m_LevelName);
        else
            Application.LoadLevel(m_LevelIndex);
        while (t>0.0f)
        {
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
            t = Mathf.Clamp01(t - Time.deltaTime / aFadeInTime);
            DrawQuad(aColor,t);
        }
        m_Fading = false;
    }
    private void StartFade(float aFadeOutTime, float aFadeInTime, Color aColor)
    {
        m_Fading = true;
        StartCoroutine(Fade(aFadeOutTime, aFadeInTime, aColor));
    }

    public static void LoadLevel(string aLevelName,float aFadeOutTime, float aFadeInTime, Color aColor)
    {
        if (Fading) return;
        Instance.m_LevelName = aLevelName;
        Instance.StartFade(aFadeOutTime, aFadeInTime, aColor);
    }
    public static void LoadLevel(int aLevelIndex,float aFadeOutTime, float aFadeInTime, Color aColor)
    {
        if (Fading) return;
        Instance.m_LevelName = "";
        Instance.m_LevelIndex = aLevelIndex;
        Instance.StartFade(aFadeOutTime, aFadeInTime, aColor);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a similar issue once. What I did was... I stopped using GL, I put a black UI.Image on the screen and changed its alpha value instead.

Comment: Yes, i know how to do that but, my question is to know what happened? why does it work in windows and not in OS X? if they are run in the same version of unity.

Comment: Did you try OpenGL mode in Windows. Unity3D default use DirectX on Windows.

Comment: follow this useful tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HwZQt94uHQ

Comment: @josegabriel I'm sorry to say, that Unity3d questions never receive much attention.

Comment: @FollowMyProposals, perhaps that's because Unity has their own Q&A site?

Comment: And perhaps people forgetting to tag with [unity3d], or mis-tagging with [unity].

Comment: Indeed, tags *are* a problem. I checked a moment ago, and the three newest Unity 3D questions were all tagged [unity] and not [unity3d].

Comment: Not to mention http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that Unity on Windows is using DirectX and not OpenGL, so it's working there (as already mentioned in the comments of your question).

Just start Unity with `-force-opengl` on Windows and you'll notice, it will stop working there either.

See http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/447206/forcing-opengl-in-windows-editor.html

Further investigation showed, that your shader is not correct for your needs. You'll need a vertex shader for that.

See http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/55392/why-my-glcolor-doesnt-work.html

e.g.:

```
Shader "Unlit Transparent Vertex Colored" 
{
    Properties 
    {
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB) Trans (A)", 2D) = "white" {}
    }

    Category 
    {
        Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
        ZWrite Off
        //Alphatest Greater 0
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha 
        Fog { Color(0,0,0,0) }
        Lighting Off
        Cull Off //we can turn backface culling off because we know nothing will be facing backwards

        BindChannels 
        {
            Bind "Vertex", vertex
            Bind "texcoord", texcoord 
            Bind "Color", color 
        }

        SubShader   
        {
            Pass 
            {
                SetTexture [_MainTex] 
                {
                    Combine texture * primary
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Source https://github.com/edbartley/BombaFiesta-Unity3D-Futile/blob/master/Assets/Resources/Shaders/UnlitTransparentVertexColored.shader

Just store that shader somewhere in `Assets/Resources` e.g. as `test.shader` and load it in `Awake()` as follows:

```
private void Awake()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
    m_Instance = this;
    var shader = Shader.Find("Unlit Transparent Vertex Colored"); // <= it's some kind of best practise to put shaders in separate files, and load them like this
    m_Material = new Material(shader);
}
```

`Shader.Find` http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Shader.Find.html

Furthermore you have to put `GL.Begin()` to the beginning of the `GL` stuff in `DrawQuad()` method.

```
private void DrawQuad(Color aColor,float aAlpha)
{
    aColor.a = aAlpha;
    m_Material.SetPass(0);

    GL.Begin(GL.QUADS); // <= put it here
    GL.Color(aColor);
    GL.PushMatrix();
    GL.LoadOrtho();
    GL.Vertex3(0, 0, -1);
    GL.Vertex3(0, 1, -1);
    GL.Vertex3(1, 1, -1);
    GL.Vertex3(1, 0, -1);
    GL.End();
    GL.PopMatrix();
}
```

Works like a charm for me, now. :-)

Let me know if you have any issues with that!

**Old Answer:**

*I kept my first answer, as it is a good alternate approach for that issue.*

It seems to be an OpenGL issue, as it's also not working on Windows with Unity 4.6.3 using `-force-opengl`, as already mentioned in the comments of your question (works fine without forcing OpenGL).

See http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/447206/forcing-opengl-in-windows-editor.html

So, I would suggest to use the following approach, as it is working on both, OpenGL and DirectX.

Just change your "DrawQuad" method as follows:

```
private void DrawQuad(Color aColor, float aAlpha)
{
    aColor.a = aAlpha;
    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
    texture.SetPixel(0, 0, aColor);
    texture.Apply();
    GUI.skin.box.normal.background = texture;
    GUI.Box(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), GUIContent.none);
}
```

See also http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/draw-a-simple-rectangle-filled-with-a-color.116348/

Answer (score 0):

Set the Graphics API to Open GL ES 2.0 in the Player Settings. This might have to do with the new iOs Metal Rendering released with Unity 4.6.3.

Comment: Ive already done that and it didnt work. The most curious thing about it is that when i try the project in my android it does the autofade. So, apparently the problem is just inside the editor. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for [GL.Color](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.Color.html), it "can only be called between GL.Begin and GL.End functions". Your call to GL.Color occurs before GL.Begin.